# Column name uniquekey is not working

Tags: mysql, node.js

I try to insert data using `Node.js` and `MySql`. I have database **table** name **my_todo** it has one column name **uniquekey** when I insert data its give following **error**.

```
{ [Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '1SPwxbFzXVZFPAx' in 'field list']
  code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sqlState: '42S22',
  index: 0 }
```

Here is my code

```
    var unik = "1SPwxbFzXVZFPAx";
    con.query("insert into my_todo(uniquekey,creator_id,todo) values("+unik+",1,this is my todo)", function (err, result){                                                                      
    if(err){ console.log(err);}
});
```

Comment: Have you googled error 1054?

Comment: its take column name as my uniquekey value. please give some suggestion.

Comment: yes, but did'n't find out.

Comment: Add that detail in to your queston, you will get a lot more helpful responses if people know what research and things you've already tried `:-)`

Comment: I would suggest encasing the string values (`this is my todo` and `unik`) in single quotes. But I do not know the syntax for node.js specifically :-/

Comment: i also tried  that.

Comment: again, ***edit*** and state that on your question so we know what you've tried and what you've not.

Comment: Please use prepared statements. You're SQL-injecting your own code ;-) You have usage examples in the linked question.